# Upload image and show it immediately on the page in ASP .Net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

To upload an image I use simple post form:

**View:**

```
<img src="@getImagePath()" />
@using(Html.BeginForm("SaveImage", "ImageController", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload image" />
}
```

**Post action:**

```
[HttpPost]
[NoCache]
public ActionResult SaveImage(HttpPostedFileBase image)
{
    SaveImage(image);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

**Page Action:**

```
[NoCache]
public ViewResult Index()
{
     return View();
}
```

So the basic scenario is: I get the page with image displayed and form to upload this image. I upload image and the page is basically reloaded so newly uploaded image should be displayed but all I see is the old image. When I refresh page manually again I see new image I uploaded. **How can I force the browser to display new image but not the one, I suggest, it stores in it's cache?** To achieve this I implemented `NoCacheAttribute` and used it for `Index` and `SaveImage` actions.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class NoCacheAttribute : FilterAttribute, IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext){}

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var cache = filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
        cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.ProxyCaches);
        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddYears(-5));
        cache.AppendCacheExtension("private");
        cache.AppendCacheExtension("no-cache=Set-Cookie");
        cache.SetProxyMaxAge(TimeSpan.Zero);
        cache.SetNoStore();
    }
}
```

But this solution didn't help me. **I still have to manually refresh the page to see newly uploaded image.**

Comment: You can set "no cache" but the browser can still ignore this header. Use a cache buster timestamp at the end of your image url `path/image.jpg?t=124849201` get a new value each time you load the page. The server should ignore this parameter but the browser sees this a a unique url and won't use the cached image.

Comment: this have to be a answer instead of a comment, thanks you for remember me that this is what make the browser to no cache content on a site.